# How to get the imageUri of own phone number?

Tags: android, phone-number, telephonymanager

I have been searching for a method to get my own phone number to retrieve the imageUri from the phone number. But there is no complete solution to get own phone number. Is there any way that we can retrieve the image of the own phone number in android?

This is how i get the imageUri from phone number.

```
public String getImageUriString(String phoneNumber)
{
    ContentResolver resolver = context.getContentResolver();
    Cursor names = resolver.query(
            Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(phoneNumber)),
            null, null, null, null);

    names.moveToFirst();
    String name = "";
    if(!names.isAfterLast())
    {
        name = names.getString(names.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.PHOTO_URI));

    }
    else
    {
        name = null;
    }

    names.close();

    return name;
}
```